# SQL query to retrive the sum of prices from specific date in a row

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add the prices and average the price with only specific dates.

```
product | price| date| month| year
------- | -----|-----|------|------
pepsi   | 34   | 01  | 05   | 2017
maaza   | 20   | 08  | 05   | 2017
fruity  | 40   | 15  | 05   | 2017
sprite  | 34   | 16  | 05   | 2017
7up     | 22   | 17  | 05   | 2017
```

For example, I want to sum and average the price of the product for the date 01/05/2017, 08/05/2017, 15/05/2017. i.e for all the Monday of the month.

So the product purchased pepsi,maaza,fruity on Mondays. 
The sum of prices would be 34+20+40 = 94. 
The average is 94/3. 

This way I would collect all the price average for

I have a basic understanding of SQL. Here's the query what I have tried

```
SELECT SUM(price) 
FROM order_history;
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Mysql and SQL server both.

Comment: Store dates/times as a single entity

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do is don't use date columns splited like that, because of many problems of working with dates, such conversion and stuff. You should work just with one column timestamp, but let's try with we have for now with [WEEKDAY](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-weekday-function.php) taking only mondays:

[image]

```
SELECT SUM(price) as sumofprice,
       AVG(price) as averageofprice
FROM order_history
WHERE WEEKDAY(year + '-' + month + '-' + year) = 0 
       AND product IN ('pepsi','maaza','fruity');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVG` aggregate function with `WHERE`, e.g.:

```
SELECT AVG(price)
FROM order_history
WHERE date IN (01, 08, 15)
AND month = 05
AND year = 2017;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [IN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx) clause to only include those `date` values that correspond to Monday:

```
SELECT SUM(price), AVG(price) 
    FROM order_history 
    WHERE month = 5 
        AND year = 2017 
        AND date IN (1, 8, 15, 22, 29)
```

(Clearly, you can update the `month` and `year` values as needed as well)

Lastly - if you had the entire date in a single column, you could easily utilize the `WEEKDAY` function to simplify this and ask for all dates that are "Monday" with something like `WHERE WEEKDAY(full_date) = 0` (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, etc)